# Swift Codable Crashing On Nested Dictionary

Tags: swift, codable

I have a complex JSON object that looks something like this (it is truncated to just give an idea of the nesting:

```
{
    "absolute_magnitude_h" = "23.4";
    ...
    "close_approach_data" = (
                {
            "close_approach_date" = "1994-09-03";
            "epoch_date_close_approach" = 778575600000;
            "orbiting_body" = Earth;
    })
    "orbital_data" =     {
        "aphelion_distance" = "4.058036874987604";
       "orbit_class" = { 
            "orbit_class_type" = APO;
        }
    }

}
```

My codable object looks like so:

```
struct NEOObj:Codable {

    var absoluteMagnitudeH:Float
    var designation:String
    var isPotentiallyHazardousAsteroid:Bool
    var isSentryObject:Bool
    var name:String
    var nasaJPLURL:String
    var neoReferenceID:String
    var closeApproachData:[NEOCloseApproachData] = [NEOCloseApproachData]()
    var orbitalData:NEOOrbitalData?

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case absoluteMagnitudeH = "absolute_magnitude_h"
        case designation = "designation"
        case isPotentiallyHazardousAsteroid = "is_potentially_hazardous_asteroid"
        case isSentryObject = "is_sentry_object"
        case name = "name"
        case nasaJPLURL = "nasa_jpl_url"
        case neoReferenceID = "neo_reference_id"
        case closeApproachData = "close_approach_data"
        case orbitalData = "orbital_data"
    }

}

struct NEOCloseApproachData:Codable {

    var closeApproachDate:String
    var orbitingBody:String
    var epochDateCloseApproach:Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case orbitingBody = "orbiting_body"
        case closeApproachDate = "close_approach_date"
        case epochDateCloseApproach = "epoch_date_close_approach"
    }
}

struct NEOOrbitalData: Codable {

    var aphelionDistance:Float

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case aphelionDistance = "aphelion_distance"
    }

}
```

and my code:

```
do {

    let thisNEOObj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(NEOObj.self, from: jsonData)
    print(thisNEOObj)
   } catch {

   }
```

I can get top level key/values with no problem (absolute_magnitude_h) for example and closeApproachData also gets populated. But if I try to retrieve orbital_data then thisNEOObj becomes nil. I haven't even attempted to retrieve orbit_class yet. : (

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: that's why you should put **print(error)** inside the catch block , try it and attach the error

Comment: Agreed with @Sh_Khan. And also i suggest that you should use optional values.

Comment: There is no error, it's just a nil object when I try to get orbital_data, if I comment that out it works.

Comment: @PruitIgoe you can try to change your `NEOOrbitalData. aphelionDistance` to Double

Comment: AphelionDistance seems to be a String. Anyway, try to decode all orbital_data by adding orbital_class. You can also try to add the init with coder and decoder so you can code and decode as you want and check in detail what's wrong

Comment: Please learn to read JSON. It's very very simple. For example everything in double quotes is `String`, even `"1.2"` and `"false"`. There is no exception.

Answer (score 0):

`"4.058036874987604"` is a `String` and cant be decoded into `var aphelionDistance: Float` without custom decoding.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you take a look at the [article](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-codable-with-custom-dates/) on Use Your Loaf that covers nested structs and handling custom transformations. You will most likely need to create a custom decoder to handle the various kinds of data transformation (although most of them will be boilerplate). You can also skip the article and review the [code over on gist](https://gist.github.com/kharrison/fec1d7fc83ffe65bf01970d71e5dc944). I believe your structs should include all of the JSON keys in the data. You might also be experiencing a problem because a Float is "A single-precision, floating-point value type", while a Double is "A double-precision, floating-point value type". Though I haven't double checked if the supplied data will cause a problem on your device but it's probably simpler to switch to the 64bit Double type.